# Data page in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to modify data pages in SQL Server in both perspective of data and size?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Size can probably be configured on database creation. What is "perspective of data" ?

Comment: The data page contains data right..is it possible to update the data..

Comment: You are supposed to only update the database using the SQL interface (DML and DDL). What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to modify data pages in SQL Server. To work with data page you can use [DBCC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188796.aspx).

Good articles with explanation of how this works:

http://www.practicalsqldba.com/2012/08/sql-server-understanding-data-page.html

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-using-dbcc-page-and-dbcc-ind-to-find-out-if-page-splits-ever-roll-back/